# Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused ¿Cómo comprobar l' IP de la instancia EC2 donde se despliega la API?

Tags: api, aws, ip, ec2

He creado un puerto túnel a la IP de la instancia EC2 donde se supone que se despliega la API (1). Conseguí el token con un pequeño script (2) pero cuando lo tecleo (3) me sale `Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused` ¿Es que no tengo los permisos? ¿O tal vez me he equivocado de IP?

1. puerto túnel a la IP de la instancia EC2 donde se supone que se despliega la API

```
    $ ssh -L<local-port>:ec2-user@<stage-or-prod-instance-ip>:<host-port> ubuntu@<stage-or-prod-bastion-ip>
```

Es mas o menos: `$ ssh -L3000:hi.hi.he.he:32980 ubuntu@ha.ha.ho.ho`. No sé qué tan sensible es esta información. En mi cabeza estoy pensando que mientras no hayamos añadido la clave SSH no es comprometedor de todos modos, ¿no?

2. Conseguí el token con el siguiente pequeño script

```
    export TOKEN=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value  \
                   --secret-id dev/api/token \
                   --query SecretString \
                   --output text | jq ".TOKEN" -r)
    
    echo $TOKEN
```

3. Lo que me sale la consulta al API:

```
    ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$  curl -XPOST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" localhost:5000/api/data/studies-metadata
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

Tal vez el IP de la instancia a la cual me connecto no es el correcto. Pero si es eso, ¿Cómo puedo comprobar las IP de los EC2 y encontrar la instancia que ejecuta la API que me interesa?

Pero parece que no hay cualquier cosa que sale del port 5000, o del 3000:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 5000
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 3000
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$
```

Pero parece que hay otros puertos que estan utilisado:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep -i tcp | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      251314/systemd-reso
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      658/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      658/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Sin el sudo, en el exterieor de la maquina:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> ssh -L3000:hi.hi.he.he:32980 ubuntu@ha.ha.ho.ho netstat -anp | findstr -i tcp | findstr -i listen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Aqui esta lo que hay en ECS del sub-red:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se como descubrir la IP de la maquina que hay la API desde aqui.

Entonces hicé clic sobre el tercero vinculo (*Container instance*) y me devuelve informaciones sobre este *Container Instance*

[image: Container instance]

No he encontrado ninguno IP publica entonces hicé clic sobre EC2 Instance:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que falta este IP. Tal vez es a causa del bastion?

Aqui esta lo que esta en la task dev-api:42:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo pienso que las IPs privadas se pueden ver con `aws ec2 describe-instances`:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-238:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" --output text
10.0.0.238      10.0.1.238
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que tienes algo corriendo en el puerto 5000 de tu localhost?  Compruébalo con `netstat -anp | grep 5000`  y mira si sale algo y si sale si esta en **LISTEN**

Comment: Segun me parece con lo que has puesto ahora no es el puerto 5000, sino el 3000

Comment: Muchas para el tuo commentario @masterguru Probé el commando pero me parece que no hay nada que salga ni de 5000  ni de 3000

Comment: Pues prueba este:  `netstat -anp | grep -i tcp | grep -i listen` para ver todos los puertos que tienes a la escucha en tu localhost y mira si los reconoces, no sea que estes lanzandolo en otro puerto por lo que sea... Si no lo encuentras es que no estas haciendo bien el tunel y te recomendaria probar de hacer un `telnet <stage-or-prod-instance-ip> <host-port>` y ver si accedes o no al servidor destino donde quieres conectarte... si te sale algo o se queda "colgado" es probable que si llegues bien... si en cambio te aparece algun error entonces habras encontrado el problema, lo lees y lo pegas

Comment: Ese netstat no es completo porque no lo has ejecutado con **sudo**... aun asi, si lanzas el tunel con `SSH -L...` sin el **sudo** si que deberia aparecer en esa lista.  Los puertos que ves abiertos son del DNS (puerto 53) y el servidor SSH (22), son normales

Comment: Sólo lo hice con SSH fuera de la caja. ¡Gracias por la orden @masterguru ! Sin embargo, el ingeniero que diseñó la API apuntaba [realmente al puerto 5000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0slqW.png), así que me pregunto si estas IPs que veo son las que busco o si me he equivocado de máquina ... La dirección que di fue dada como ejemplo, pero como se trata de un proyecto muy pequeño, y si el ssh a esta máquina funciona debe ser la correcta? Bueno, me voy a dar un paseo, este proyecto me está volviendo loco.

Comment: Bueno, lo que queda claro es que la api no esta corriendo en la instancia donde ejecutas al comando. ¿Que es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? ¿Enviar peticiones  cada una de las maquinas de la subred y probar si ahí esta la api? ¿Cómo es que no sabes la instancia en que se ejecuta tu api?

Comment: ¿Enviar peticiones cada una de las maquinas de la subred y probar si ahí esta la api? Si puede funcionar, ¿Por qué no @JaimeMenéndez ? He oído que de lo contrario puedo encontrarlo a través de ECS con la consola de AWS. No lo sé porque acabo de llegar al proyecto, ... y ni siquiera soy devops.

Comment: No se por qué dices que es "Lo contrario". No veo nada contrapuesto de lo que dices y lo que te dije. De cualquier manera puedes ver las ip privadas de tus instancias con algo cómo `aws ec2 describe-instances  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" --output text` y hacer un script en batch que pruebe conectarse una por una y ver si obtienes una respuesta exitosa de alguna de ellas. Si hay conectividad ni siquiera tienes que conectarte por ssh, usando en el curl con la ip podrías obtener respuesta. Usa `aws ec2 describe-instances` para que veas todo lo que puedes obtener.

Comment: Por otro lado, hay tantas cosas que pueden influir en el que obtengas una respuesta y tan pocos detalles en la pregunta. No sé si tienes los puertos abiertos y los permisos suficientes en cada una de tus instancias, no se si tienes ACL o security groups que restrinjan el acceso. No se sabe nada de la arquitectura de tu servicio. No dices nada de cómo está levantada tu app. ¿Se usó Elastic Beanstalk? ¿Se levantó directamente con una instancia EC2? Poco se puede hacer y es que no me explico cómo no puede conocer uno en dónde está el servicio. Parece algún tipo de juego de adivinación.

Comment: Lo siento, @JaimeMenéndez , me expresé mal. Gracias por tu comando `aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress" --output text` ¡Realmente tengo otra dirección IP que apareció junto a la mía! Pero de momento no tengo ni idea de cómo conectarme a él. Sí, es cierto que es muy cutre dejarme solo para intentar encontrar dónde están las cosas. El documento no es realmente para la gente que no ha estado en el proyecto desde el principio y especialmente aquellos que son nuevos en AWS.

Comment: ¡Genial! Y genial por tu foto. Ya más o menos veo un enviroment que está hecho en ECS. Tienes dos contenedores, uno con una api y otro que será una app de Vue. Dado que buscas la api, supongo que tú estás conectado al contenedor `service-dev-vue` (Que bueno, todavía no corre ninguna app de vue por lo que muestras en la salida de la consola.). Ahora bien, si das click ahí en cualquiera de las dos task en la consola puedes ver el ip que tienen, tanto el público como el privado. Busca desde la consola de aws el ip de la api. ¿Lo encontraste?

Comment: Cuando lo encuentres intenta `curl -XPOST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" <ip de la api>:5000/api/data/studies-metadata` desde la máquina donde estás (que supongo sea la de vue). ¿Obtuviste algo?

Comment: Ha, no sé si fue conectado al contenedor `service-dev-vue`. Hicé un clic sobre la task `dev-api:42` pero no he encontrado ninguno ip publico @JaimeMenéndez

Comment: O sea, esos comandos que estás ejecutando, ¿Los estás ejecutando desde tu máquina? Pensé que estabas conectado remoto a alguna de las dos instancias. ¿ Lo primero que dijiste no fue que te conectabas por ssh?

Comment: Si, hicé un ssh desde un powershell. Tambien supongo que fue conectado al contenedor `service-dev-vue`. Pero hasta que no conozco quien es quien no puedo ser seguro @JaimeMenéndez